# My javascript isnt showing up in my browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

DETAILS: So basically i'm a JS noob. Nothing happens when I open this in chrome besides the H1 title. Please help.

HTML file code.
`<!doctype HTML>`
`<html>`
`<head>`

`</head>`

`<body>`
`<h1> Welcome to battleship! </h1>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="battleship.js"></script>`

`</body>`

`</html>`

JAVASCRIPT CODE. The name is "battleship.js", just in case you were wondering.

```
//location of ship
var location1 = 3;
var location2 = 4;
var location3 = 5;

//number of guesses 
var guess;
var guesses = 0;
var hits = 0;

//is the ship sunk?
var isSunk = false;

while (isSunk == false) {
    guess = prompt("Ready, aim, FIRE! Enter a number 0 - 9 to hit the ship!");

    if (guess > 6 || guess < 0) {
        alert("Please enter a valid number fool!");
    } else {
        guesses = guesses + 1;
    }
if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
    hits = hits + 1;
    if (hits == 3) {
        alert("You sank my B ship hombre");
    }
    }
    }
}
var stats = "You took " + guesses + " guesses to sink the battleship. Your accuracy is " + (3/guesses);
```

Comment: are the JS file and HTML file in same directory?

Comment: There’s a syntax error. Look at the browser console, copy your JS code into [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) and use consistent indentation.

Comment: Thanks @Xufox, Ill definitely be sure to us JShint in the future. Very helpful. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Check that your script and HTML file are stored in the same folder and also check that you don't have any error on your script. If the script has any errors won't be executed as expected.

It seems that you have written an extra } at the end of the script